# How do i resolve the react-router v6 Link element error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to build a simple react-native application and facing the following issue in my code. If I remove the `<Link>` component and keep the `<Text>` component, error is going away. If I try to keep the `<Link>` component and remove the `<Text>` component, error comes back.

Can anyone please help me with this?

```
import * as React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import { Link } from "react-router-native";

function Home() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Welcome!</Text>
      <Link to="/profile">Visit your profile</Link>
    </View>
  );
}
```

> Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element
> child.

Comment: From looking at the docs of react router native, it seems like you'll have to wrap `Visit your profile` in a `<Text>` element, just like you did right above. EDIT: link of said docs: https://v5.reactrouter.com/native/api/Link || further explanation: it seems like Node interprets `Visit`, `your` and `profile` as 3 distinct elements (not even React elements, hence the precision in the error).

Comment: Thank you @GaëtanBoyals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `react-router` **V6**  docs say that `<Link>` renders a `TouchableHighlight` and  it must have at least (and most) one child and also must be wrapped in a `<View>` element. Please change your implementation as follows.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import {Link} from 'react-router-native';

function Home() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Welcome!</Text>
      <Link to="/profile">
        <Text>Visit your profile</Text>
      </Link>
    </View>
  );
}
```

If you want to override default styling and behavior, please refer to the Props reference for [TouchableHighlight](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchablehighlight#props).

Answer (score 2):

In **v6 react-router**, The `<Link>` should have exactly 1 element. But in your case, The text `Visit`, `your` and `profile` is being assumed as **3 text nodes**.

To make it as one element, You can simply wrap it into `<Text>`. So the `<Link>` will have only one `<Text>` element but that has **3 text nodes** inside which is not a problem to `<Link>`

```
function Home() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Welcome!</Text>
      <Link to="/profile">
         <Text>Visit your profile<Text>
      </Link>
    </View>
  );
}
```